Torque Create by a propeller
I am working in a robotics project for a holomonic Drone, and I am having some difficulties understanding how a propeller generate thrust.
My robot currently has 6 motors + rotors, all the motor are reversible, meaning we can spin the motor in CCW and CW motion, but the propellers have a profile (3 CCW and 3 CW), obviously this mean some loss in actuation force when the propeller is spinning against its normal direction.
But the main question of this post is, assuming we have no loss of performance when CCW is rotated in CW motion (and vice-versa), if I have a motor with CCW rotating in CCW will the torque be the same if we have a motor with CCW rotation and CW propeller?
Honestly the question can be rephrased in a much simpler way, does the profile of the propeller change anything in torque generated (in an ideal world, where parameters are the same in reverse motion), or by simply rotating in the reverse (negative rpm's) we simply invert the thrust?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/724588/why-does-this-fan-with-one-blade-missing-rotates-counterclockwise-while-running
